# Can I update Amazon's old versions of pip and setuptools?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, setuptools

Can I update or remove the pip and setuptools provided with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

The versions of pip and setuptools provided with my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python environments (in the 2.7 virtual environment running my application, `ami-d14608e1`; in `/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`) are very old: as reported by

```
pip list --outdated
```

they are

```
setuptools (Current: 2.2 Latest: 12.0.5)
pip (Current: 1.5.4 Latest: 6.0.7)
```

Can I update these (e.g. by listing them in my `requirements.txt`) or are these specific versions expected by or needed for EB's Python and deployment processes to work?

Answer (score 34):

Taking `pip` as an example, the default AWS environment provides usually an old version. Currently it is a `6.1.1` on a machine I use, while `pip` repeats at each call that `9.0.1` is available.

Dependencies sometimes require recent versions of `pip`. One way to have it available is to rely on `pip` itself, as the `yum` sources provided by AWS are slower to upgrade (due to the sheer impact that would cause...).

Different AWS services have different solutions. The question is about Beanstalk. Assuming deployment based on `eb` provided by AWS, it is possible to execute commands in the target container:

- Create a `.ebextensions/upgrade_pip.config` file.
- Insert the command to execute.

To upgrade `pip`, a command like this does the job:

```
commands:
  pip_upgrade:
    command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
    ignoreErrors: false
```

Note that the file name for `.ebextensions/upgrade_pip.config` defines the order of execution. If it needs to run earlier than any other script in `.ebextensions`, a prefix like `01_upgrade...` is necessary.

Comment: Is this still meant to work, because it appears to be totally ignored by my deployment? Possibly outdated, or should this work?

Comment: @CodeSpent I have just tried and it still works. [Here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1892643) is a snippet of the code and server log.

Comment: Yea, what do I tell EBcli in order to get ebextension to run?

Comment: @jwillis0720 If you follow the pattern set up by AWS (files under `.ebextensions`), they should be picked when executing commands. For more information, the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) provides examples.

Comment: also I told pip to update itself in the requirements file first thing

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an ebextension file that will upgrade pip before running
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

for example:

004_prehook.config

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/02a_upgrade_pip.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
      python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Hey Yarh, It's not working for me... How can I understand what's going wrong? I have started on AWS 14 days ago, and I never thought that AWS would have so poor documentation to do simple stuff... It's very frustrating